# Declare list of objects in Spring application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

In a Spring Boot application, I would like to be able to declare a list of my domain objects in my `application.properties` file and read them as a `List<TheDomainObject>` as a `Bean`.

For example, let's say I have the following in `application.properties`:

```
com.application.person.john.name=John Smith
com.application.person.john.home-directory=/Users/john.smith
com.application.person.john.private-key-file=/Users/john.smith/.ssh/id_rsa

com.application.person.adam.name=Adam Bell
com.application.person.adam.home-directory=/Users/adam.bell
com.application.person.adam.private-key-file=/Users/adam.bell/.ssh/id_rsa

etc
```

I.e. I'd like to have properties for each person grouped under a key. I'd be able to add as many keys (people) as I like.

I would not need to reference these properties directly, but I'd like to declare a Domain object as follows (abbreviated):

```
class Person {
  String id;   (this would be the 'key', i.e. 'john', 'adam')
  String name;
  Path homeDirectory;
  Path privateKeyFile;

  // boilerplate
}
```

and then receive a `List<Person>` through `Configuration`.  The more automatic the better, but I would be more than happy to implement builders or some additional converter logic if needed.

I can't find any documentation for this kind of thing, but I have seen it in **log4j** for example, where you can dynamically add logging properties for any package name, so it must be possible to at least retrieve those keys.

I know I can do this differently, for example by using a `data.sql` import script, however in my case it would be very ideal to have this in a single properties file (or yaml) format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use **id** as an explicit property?

for example (yaml):

```
com:
  application:
    persons:
      - 
        id: john
        name: John Smith
        home-directory: /Users/john.smith
      - 
        id: adam 
        name: Adam Bell
        home-directory: /Users/adam.bell
```

This would resolve in `List<Person> persons;`

Comment: That would be ideal.  How would I resolve that to a `List<Person>`?

Comment: by using @ConfigurationProperties. See: https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `@ConfigurationProperties`
It will help you in this scenario, right?

Please refer for more details

https://www.techiedelight.com/map-spring-boot-properties-to-pojo

https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

definition with application.properties format

```
com.application.persons=[{id=john, name=John Smith, home-directory=/Users/john.smith}, {id=adam, name=Adam Bell, home-directory=/Users/adam.bell}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is possible do this definition with application.properties format?

```
com:
  application:
    persons:
      - 
        id: john
        name: John Smith
        home-directory: /Users/john.smith
      - 
        id: adam 
        name: Adam Bell
        home-directory: /Users/adam.bell
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32255935)

Comment: `com.application.persions[0].id=john` etc... (but I think you need to specifically define name and home-directory also in the same way at the same time - e.g. `com.application.persions[0].name=John Smith`).